# What is the cheapest CPU that supports virtualization?

Tags: graphics-cards, processor, virtual-machines, intel

I am looking for a cheap CPU that supports virtualization. However, I do not know which CPU is better. Right now I'm looking for a CPU that supports an OS using QubesOS, a Xen virtualization technology. I have a Lenovo Thinkpad x230.
Purpose of use

We do not play games, videos, or videos with high image quality. Basically, I'm going to run several VMs at the same time to search, email, and program in the browser, so I don't need a very high quality CPU like the Mac Pro. I can't afford my wallet.

The following are required for this OS: ()
Minimum

```
64-bit Intel or AMD processor (x86_64 aka x64 aka AMD64)

Intel VT-x with EPT or AMD-V with RVI

Intel VT-d or AMD-Vi (aka AMD IOMMU)

4 GB RAM

32 GiB disk space
```

Recommended

```
Fast SSD (strongly recommended)

Intel IGP (strongly preferred)

    Nvidia GPUs may require significant troubleshooting.

    AMD GPU s have not been formally tested, but Radeons (RX580 and earlier) generally work well
```

Also, please tell me about the following questions about CPU.

```
What are cheap and good quality manufacturers? (I don't need brand power.) In my opinion, Intel and AMD are equal in quality. Intel has a higher idea.

How long is the life of the CPU? Or how many years should I buy a new one?
```

Comment: Changing CPU in a laptop, even one so well documented as an x230, is highly not  recommended. In general, a motherboard has a specific socket. That and its BIOS dictate what CPUs will work. Do you have a desktop PC available? What motherboard does it have?

Comment: In a Thinkpad X230, the CPU is soldered to the motherboard anyway. Swapping in a different CPU either requires changing the board, or it involves rather expensive equipment to de- and re-solder. The question reads like there might be some confusion about what a CPU actually is. I have seen people refer to a desktop PC tower as "the CPU"...

Answer (score -1):

Q: *What are cheap and good quality manufacturers? (I don't need brand power.) In my opinion, Intel and AMD are equal in quality. Intel has a higher idea.* There are three major CPU manufacturers on the market today: Intel, AMD, and whoever is making [RISC/ARM processors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_instruction_set_computer#Use_of_RISC_architectures).

Although RISC is known to have a Windows port in development, it is not readily available, so that brings us back to Intel and AMD. Both of them make CPUs of high quality which can last so long, they will go completely obsolete before they fail, if there's no physical abuse of the CPU.

As to Cheapness, Intel and AMD are not in the Cheap business, but they have stayed in business, demonstrating Quality. The price/performance ratio of Intel and AMD CPUs are carefully tracked in the computer trade press, and you must draw your own conclusion as to which is a better buy.

Q: *How long is the life of the CPU? Or how many years should I buy a new one?* [Many years to decades](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/long-processors-last-71800.html).

Of course, we're talking about the [CPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_processing_unit) chip here, not any other component of a PC.  That's what you asked about. The other components of a PC drastically affect the price and performance of a system, so focusing on just the CPU may be counterproductive.

Comment: The remaining issues you asked about should be removed from the question my your clicking [edit], removing their text from the original question, and creating a new question with their text. As per https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic, the site's _Quality Guidelines:_ Your question on Hardware Recommendations should:: 
Show previous research - Tell us what products you are aware of that do not meet your needs. and Have a narrow scope - Only ask for one piece of hardware at a time and focus on what you need from that item. If you need multiple items, ask more than one question.